# Xamarin Forms: sporadic crashes since porting to WkWebView

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, wkwebview, crash-reports, watchdog

We ported our app from UIWebView to WkWebView.

Since then the app crashes sporadically (sometimes after minutes, sometimes after hours, sometimes not at all) while being in background.

Looking at the termination reason 0x8badf00d (see crash report below) and Apple's developer documentation ([Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)) the crash seems to be related to a watchdog timeout.

The only task we start in our code while the app moves to background is embedded in appropriate calls to UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask and UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask. That task is a network request that does not run on the main UI thread and it completes within a second.

That said I assume the crash to be related to a WebKit / JavaScriptCore issue.

Did anyone else experience such crashes (exception type EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGKILL) & termination reason Namespace ASSERTIOND, Code 0x8badf00d) and can provide any specific hint about how to avoid them?

Many thanks in advance & best regards!

Mario.

```
Incident Identifier: 2084FF7B-EDFB-41D4-849F-E03F75335214
CrashReporter Key:   0af317c4eee2f011df0e1a9fc253199241998699
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,6
Process:             App [1798]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A4FF0F47-4ED6-4A97-8F15-E6AC432FC62D/App.app/App
Identifier:          com.abc.app
Version:             7000025 (7.0.25)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.abc.app [792]


Date/Time:           2019-03-20 10:15:43.9491 +0100
Launch Time:         2019-03-20 09:55:44.7537 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1.4 (16D57)
Baseband Version:    2.02.51
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGKILL)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4370874368
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104864000-0000000105bdc000 [ 19.5M] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...honeMobileiOS

Termination Reason: Namespace ASSERTIOND, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001841bef0c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184241410 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 620
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b95b7d8 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait+ 305112 (WTF::Mutex&, WTF::WallTime) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b9429a0 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void + 203168 ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2004
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b91c2e4 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>+ 45796 (WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 184
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018b920010 WTF::BinarySemaphore::wait+ 61456 (WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType) + 112
6   WebKit                          0x000000019400a2b0 IPC::Connection::waitForSyncReply+ 455344 (unsigned long long, WTF::Seconds, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendSyncOption>) + 276
7   WebKit                          0x0000000194009af8 IPC::Connection::sendSyncMessage+ 453368 (unsigned long long, std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Encoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Encoder> >, WTF::Seconds, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendSyncOption>) + 416
8   WebKit                          0x00000001942cac3c bool IPC::Connection::sendSync<Messages::WebProcess::ProcessWillSuspendImminently>+ 3341372 (Messages::WebProcess::ProcessWillSuspendImminently&&, Messages::WebProcess::ProcessWillSuspendImminently::Reply&&, unsigned long long, WTF::Seconds, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendSyncOption>) + 176
9   WebKit                          0x00000001942c5a70 bool WebKit::ChildProcessProxy::sendSync<Messages::WebProcess::ProcessWillSuspendImminently>+ 3320432 (Messages::WebProcess::ProcessWillSuspendImminently&&, Messages::WebProcess::ProcessWillSuspendImminently::Reply&&, unsigned long long, WTF::Seconds, WTF::OptionSet<IPC::SendSyncOption>) + 120
10  WebKit                          0x00000001942c59e8 WebKit::WebProcessProxy::sendProcessWillSuspendImminently+ 3320296 () + 76
11  WebKit                          0x0000000193fafabc -[WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager _notifyClientsOfImminentSuspension] + 72
12  WebKit                          0x00000001940ea7fc __64-[WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager _updateBackgroundTask]_block_invoke + 168
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b1801a8c _fireBackgroundExpirationHandlers + 300
14  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187057504 __69-[FBSUIApplicationWorkspace clientHandleAssertionExpirationImminent:]_block_invoke + 76
15  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018706ae94 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 64
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184062484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001840393e0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
18  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018709fa9c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
19  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018709f728 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 416
20  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018709fd44 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845ba0e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845ba060 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b9944 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b4810 __CFRunLoopRun + 1040
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845b40e0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
26  GraphicsServices                0x000000018682d584 GSEventRunModal + 100
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b1804c00 UIApplicationMain + 212
28  Xamarin.Sdk                     0x0000000106da9518 0x106224000 + 12080408
29  Xamarin.Sdk                     0x0000000106cfac8c 0x106224000 + 11365516
30  Xamarin.Sdk                     0x0000000106cfac4c 0x106224000 + 11365452
31  App                             0x00000001049cf7fc App_Application_Main_string__ + 1488892 (/<unknown>:1)
32  Xamarin.Sdk                     0x0000000106526bb8 0x106224000 + 3156920
33  Mono                            0x0000000105fd7374 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 904
34  Mono                            0x000000010605d1a0 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148
35  Mono                            0x0000000106063084 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 120
36  Mono                            0x0000000105fb6c1c mono_jit_exec + 268
37  Xamarin                         0x0000000105d76cc8 xamarin_main + 1132
38  App                             0x00000001049c8e4c main + 1461836 (main.m:155)
39  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000184072bb4 start + 4
```

Comment: I suggest that you can use APP Center to analyse the error log.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT App Center Diagnostics would be of no use in this case as the app gets killed (SIGKILL) and therefore there won't be any .NET runtime exception.